How to properly control speed of sprite scaling to create "hallway" effect
I'm working on a project (in Gamemaker GML, so JS-like) that involves manipulating 2D sprites (scale and position only) to generate a(n intentionally hacky) visual illusion of moving down a 3D hallway.
Basically, I have a vanishing point at the screen center, and 4 identical trapezoidal tiles representing the walls/floor/ceiling at the maximum scale and position. The tile looks like this:

What I want to do is scale and reposition four "layers" of these tiles linearly from the center of the screen, replacing fully-scaled tiles with new ones at minimum scale, to simulate the effect of traveling "through" the hallway created by the looping images.
The effect is working somewhat, insomuch as I can generate the "room" from the tiles, like this:

The problem occurs when I try to get everything moving. Right now, all tiles are drawn from their "top-center", so the floor tile's origin is at (half_width, 0), the ceiling's is at (half_width, height), etc. Each "layer" of 4 tiles has a scale value that increases from 0.24 to 1.6 (magic numbers that fit the visual effect I want). Every step, the changing vector position of each sub-tile (x for walls, y for floor and ceiling) is multiplied by the scale value, and the overall X/Y size of the image is also set to the current scale value.
As you can see, it sorta works. The problem is that the lower-scale-value images keep "overtaking" the larger ones, AKA the larger tiles appear to move more and more slowly as they near their maximum scale.

I'm assuming there's some basic math I'm missing here around the way perspective alters the perceived speed at which approaching objects move? If I was working in proper or even psuedo-3D (some sort of perspective-based rendering of quads) this would be a non issue, of course, but for arbitrary reasons I'm trying to work this with pre-skewed tiles.
Any assistance much appreciated. This feels very much like an "I don't quite know the question I'm asking" situation, but after many searches I'm at a slight impasse and would be grateful for pointers!


Right now, all tiles are drawn from their "top-center", so the floor tile's origin is at (half_width, 0), the ceiling's is at (half_width, height), etc.

The math will be simpler if you change the origin of each sprite so that it is at the vanishing point, which is the point at which the sloping lines on the sprite meet, which is also the center of the scene. If you do that, then the sprites never need to be translated, only scaled. (Of course, you can also set up the origin and transforms differently, as long as it produces the same end result..)
Assuming you have done that, we can then say that the second part of the problem is that the scales need to be changed in a fashion that is not linear interpolation. That is, suppose layer 2 is currently 1.8 times as large as layer 1. Then, in order for layer 3 to meet layer 2 in the same way that layer 2 meets layer 1, layer 3 must be 1.8 times as large as layer 2, and therefore 1.82 times as large as layer 1.
This relationship can be expressed, and the passage of animation time incorporated, as this function:
scale(i) = pow(scale_step, i + animation_progress)
where i is the layer number, scale_step is the constant I gave as 1.8 above (which should be set to match your actual sprite design), and animation_progress is a number that goes from 0.0 to 1.0 repeatedly. Each time animation_progress loops back to zero, it's as if a large layer was deleted and replaced with a small layer.

Amazing, thanks so much for this! And good point re: orienting the sprites to the vanishing point rather than individual relative origins.
I actually inched closer to something resembling the pow function this afternoon by multiplying each tile's scale by a factor (say 1.01 times its current scale) every step rather than increasing it linearly, but your explanation and implementation is far clearer.
Really appreciate the guidance!

@bryinlyin Multiplying by a constant factor every frame does have the same effect mathematically, but it will accumulate rounding error (probably not enough to notice) and is not as simple to configure in terms of what you want the looping period to be.

Pinhole camera basics for drawing lines in perspective
What you're trying to implement is called a pinhole camera. You can easily implement this in code. If you do so, your demo will not be "hacky", you'll have a consistent renderer without having to address weird edge cases. I'm sure that's preferable to head-scratching?
You're representing discrete, point-like objects in 3D space, on the screen. This means you should have an (x,y,z) coordinate for each (point-style) object in the world. Then the way to get the screen coordinates is:
//calculated as individual x and y components:

xScreen = xWorld / zWorld + halfScreenWidth;
yScreen = yWorld / zWorld + halfScreenHeight;

//or in swizzled vector notation:

screen.xy = world.xy / world.z;


To draw lines, you're just going to calculate the screen position of the two endpoints of each line, and rasterise a line between them.
Additional info if drawing sprites in your pinhole camera
You should draw around the point, meaning if you use larger sprites, they should be centred on the point (minus half sprite width off to one side of the xScreen, and plus half sprite width off to the other side; do the same for Screen and sprite height).
Then you also need to scale each discrete object when you draw it:
scale = 1 / zWorld;

Thus, when you have an object sitting at zWorld == 1, it will be scaled as 1:1 (since 1/1 = 1), and every 1 unit you move in x or y will equate to 1 pixel.
Again, for lines, you can also scale their thickness based on the same formula.
It is absolutely trivial to implement, give it a try.
(Disclaimer: I use xWorld / zWorld in this answer. While calling these world space coordinates is fine for a a camera that is fixed and never rotates in any axis, it is true that for a rotating camera, we would first convert each point into camera space coordinates, and then use the above formula which would in fact be xScreen = xCamera / zCamera + halfScreenWidth etc. Again, if your camera never rotates, camera and world mean the same thing).
